# How to align content in a flex box using Tailwind

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I am working with `flex` in Tailwind CSS and I have content that's not being aligned correctly.

```html
    <div class="flex flex-col space-y-4 p-2 w-full">
       <div class="flex space-x-2">
          <p class="w-1/4 text-sm"> python </p>
          <div class="h-4 w-1/2 rounded-md mt-1 bg-green-400" style="width: 65%;"></div>
          <p class="w-1/4 text-sm"> 65 </p>
       </div>
       <div class="flex space-x-2">
          <p class="w-1/4 text-sm"> html </p>
          <div class="h-4 w-1/2 rounded-md mt-1 bg-green-400" style="width: 100%;"></div>
          <p class="w-1/4 text-sm"> 100 </p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

The HTML is rending like this:

[image]

As you see in the graph, the first green line aligns in the center, but I want it to align to the left.

I tried many ways, adding `justify-start`, `center-start`, etc., but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

with css you can apply at your field

```
.left {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just wrap the bar and the value in another `flex` to keep them together. For example:

```html
  <div class="flex w-full space-x-2">
    <p class="basis-1/4 text-sm">python</p>
    <div class="basis-3/4 flex items-center space-x-2">
      <div class="h-4 rounded-md bg-green-400" style="width: 65%;"></div>
      <div class="flex-1 text-sm">65</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The `flex-1` on the value will eat up the rest of the space on that row so that the value sticks to the end of the bar.

Working example here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/M9xW90axaY